# Restaurar dados

Tags: android, persistência, entrada-de-dados

Estou criando um app que contém um formulário e quando o usuario clica em um campo de busca de endereço ele é levado pra outra activity e depois esse endereço é recuperado em um textView na activity inicial(a do formulário).Para busca de endereço estou usando o **Google Places AutoComplete**. Porém quando a aplicação volta para essa activity inicial os outros campos do formulário que já haviam sido preenchidos perdem seus dados e aparecem vazios novamente. Fiz o Log e vi que a activity está sendo destruída e o onCreate está sendo executado novamente. Por isso tentei salvar os dados com o **onSaveInstanceState** e depois restaurá-los com o **onRestoreInstanceState** mas ainda assim nada mudou. Gostaria de saber se utilizar esses métodos seria realmente a melhor solução e se eu os fiz corretamente ou se teria outra solução mais adequada.

Abaixo segue os códigos da classe do formulário e da classe de busca de endereço:

**Classe do formulário**:

```
 @Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    Log.d("CicloA","SaveInstance");
    final EditText textBox1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_NomeEvent);

    CharSequence userText = textBox1.getText();
    outState.putCharSequence("savedText", userText);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    Log.d("CicloA","Restore");

    final EditText textBox1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_NomeEvent);

    CharSequence userText = savedInstanceState.getCharSequence("savedText");
    textBox1.setText(userText);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_criar_evento);

    Log.d("CicloA","onCreate");

    storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();


    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Criar evento");

    dados.add("Festas e Baladas");
    dados.add("Música ao vivo");
    dados.add("Aprender");
    dados.add("Negócios");
    dados.add("Cultura");
    dados.add("Bem estar");


    spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_T);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,dados);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            informacaoSelecionada = dados.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });


    editTextNomeEvento = findViewById(R.id.editText_NomeEvent);
    editTextDescricao = findViewById(R.id.editText_descricao);


    txtDataEventoInicio = findViewById(R.id.txt_DataEventInicio);
    cdwDataEventoInicio = findViewById(R.id.cdw_DataEventInicio);
    cdwDataEventoInicio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            flag = FLAG_START_DATE;
            scheduleHoraData(v);
        }
    });

    txtDataEventoFim = findViewById(R.id.txt_DataEventFim);
    cdwDataEventoFim = findViewById(R.id.cdw_DataEventFim);
    cdwDataEventoFim.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            flag = FLAG_END_DATE;
            scheduleHoraData2(v);
        }
    });

    txtendereco = findViewById(R.id.txt_endereco);
    txtendereco.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MapActivity.class));
        }

    });

    Intent intentReceber = getIntent();
    Bundle parametro = intentReceber.getExtras();

    if (parametro != null) {

       String endereco = parametro.getString("chave_endereco");
        txtendereco.setText(endereco);

    }


    cdwImgEvento = findViewById(R.id.cardView_uploadEvento);
    imageViewEvento = findViewById(R.id.img_uploadEvento);

    final LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_descricao_img);


    imageViewEvento.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            permissao();
            obterImagem_Galeria();

            linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });


    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();


}
```

**Classe de Busca do endereço:**

@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        materialSearchBar = findViewById(R.id.searchBar);

```
    mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(MapActivity.this);

    placesClient = Places.createClient(this);
    final AutocompleteSessionToken token = AutocompleteSessionToken.newInstance();


    materialSearchBar.setOnSearchActionListener(new MaterialSearchBar.OnSearchActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSearchStateChanged(boolean enabled) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onSearchConfirmed(CharSequence text) {
            startSearch(text.toString(), true, null, true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onButtonClicked(int buttonCode) {
            if (buttonCode == MaterialSearchBar.BUTTON_NAVIGATION) {
            } else if (buttonCode == MaterialSearchBar.BUTTON_BACK) {
                materialSearchBar.disableSearch();
                startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), CriarEventoActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        }
    });
    materialSearchBar.addTextChangeListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest predictionsRequest = FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest.builder()
                    .setCountry("br")
                    .setTypeFilter(TypeFilter.ADDRESS)
                    .setTypeFilter(TypeFilter.ESTABLISHMENT)
                    .setSessionToken(token)
                    .setQuery(s.toString())
                    .build();
            placesClient.findAutocompletePredictions(predictionsRequest).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<FindAutocompletePredictionsResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<FindAutocompletePredictionsResponse> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        FindAutocompletePredictionsResponse predictionsResponse = task.getResult();
                        if (predictionsResponse != null) {
                            predictionList = predictionsResponse.getAutocompletePredictions();
                            List<String> suggestionsList = new ArrayList<>();
                            for (int i = 0; i < predictionList.size(); i++) {
                                AutocompletePrediction prediction = predictionList.get(i);
                                suggestionsList.add(prediction.getFullText(null).toString());
                            }
                            materialSearchBar.updateLastSuggestions(suggestionsList);
                            if (!materialSearchBar.isSuggestionsVisible()) {
                                materialSearchBar.showSuggestionsList();
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.i("mytag", "prediction fetching task unsuccesful");
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });


    materialSearchBar.setSuggstionsClickListener(new SuggestionsAdapter.OnItemViewClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void OnItemClickListener(int position, View v) {
            if(position >= predictionList.size()){
                return;
            }

            AutocompletePrediction selectedPrediction = predictionList.get(position);
            String suggestion = materialSearchBar.getLastSuggestions().get(position).toString();
            materialSearchBar.setText(suggestion);


            Intent intentEnviar = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CriarEventoActivity.class);
            Bundle parametro = new Bundle();
            parametro.putString("chave_endereco",suggestion);

            intentEnviar.putExtras(parametro);
            startActivity(intentEnviar);
            finish();


            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    materialSearchBar.clearSuggestions();
                }
            }, 1000);
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            if(imm != null)
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(materialSearchBar.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
            final String placeId = selectedPrediction.getPlaceId();
            List<Place.Field> placeFields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.LAT_LNG);

            FetchPlaceRequest fetchPlaceRequest = FetchPlaceRequest.builder(placeId, placeFields).build();
            placesClient.fetchPlace(fetchPlaceRequest).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FetchPlaceResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(FetchPlaceResponse fetchPlaceResponse) {
                    Place place = fetchPlaceResponse.getPlace();
                    Log.i("mytag", "Place found: " + place.getName());



                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    if(e instanceof ApiException){
                        ApiException apiException = (ApiException) e;
                        apiException.printStackTrace();
                        int statusCode = apiException.getStatusCode();
                        Log.i("mytag", "place not found: " + e.getMessage());
                        Log.i("mytag", "status code: " + statusCode);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void OnItemDeleteListener(int position, View v) {

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Não é fácil seguir a lógica do seu código. Tenha em atenção que o método *onRestoreInstanceState* só é chamado após o *onStart*. Como toda a lógica de inicialização está no *onCreate* é possível que seja essa a causa do problema. Talvez seja preferível usar o Bundle recebido no *onCreate*.

Comment: Ok. Vou verificar isso. Obrigada.